# Random cellular automaton with three colors.

Tags: automata

Does exist a Cellular Automata Rule that is RANDOM (like rule 30) and has 3 colors?

I mean, as Wolfram says in his book, rule 30 shows a random behavior with some limits. But this happens using 2 colors (k=2). For my analysis I need of a random rule with k=3. Is it possible to implement?

Regards,

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalisticCellularAutomaton.html)?

Comment: Yes I saw it, but is the code 777 random? I need of this rule because I want to simulate a random behavior.

Comment: Rule 30 isn't truly "random". It's only pseudo-random.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a research problem - you have to run statistical tests on the Cellular Automata (CA) Rule you find to show that it is random. If you would like to do a research projects like this check out  [**The Wolfram Science Summer School**](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/).

For now let see what information and tools can get you started.

First of all I would read [**Chapter 6: Starting from Randomness - Section 5: Randomness in Class 3 Systems**](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/section-6.5) in the "New Kind of Science" (NKS) book and surounding chapters for better understanding of the subject.

I would also look at [**many free apps exploring 3-color rules**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=three%20color%20cellular%20automata) at The Wolfram Demonstrations Project.

Next you can start from good candidates found on [**page 64**](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-64#previous). Follow that link and read the image captions about 3-color CAs with seamingly random behavior. The online book is free (you may need to register once). I would recommend also reading pages 62 - 70 exaplaining those images.

Also take a look at [**"Random Sequence Generation by Cellular Automata" by Stephen Wolfram**](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/articles/ca/86-random/).

If you do no thave Mathematica, then Wolfram|Alpha can provide tons of valuable information. Here are the queries for the CAs from NKS book: [**rule 177**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k-3%20r-1%20totalistic%20rule%20177), [**rule 912**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k-3%20r-1%20totalistic%20rule%20912), and [**rule 2040**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k-3%20r-1%20totalistic%20rule%202040). Note how Wolfram|Alpha gives you, for example, [**difference pattern**](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-949e-text) images - higly divergent (spread fast) means chaos and randomness:

[image]

If you have [**Mathematica**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) - it is easy to evolve CAs (and further test their random properties say with [**Chi-squared test**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi-SquaredTest.html)). This is how you set up a 3 color range 1 totalistic CAs from pictures in NKS book (you can dig further with [**Hypothesis Testing**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/HypothesisTests.html)).

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[{#, {3, 1}}, {{1}, 0}, 50], Mesh -> True, 
    PixelConstrained -> 7, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}, 
    Epilog -> Text[Style["Rule " <> ToString@#, Red, Bold, 25], {50, 340}]] & /@ 
{177, 912, 2040} // Column
```

[image]